# Best practice to use bitwise parameter combinations using enums?

Tags: c++, enums, state, bitwise-operators

I am implementing a view that lives on a screen. Based on the following configuration parameters the view will be positioned and resized whenever the screen size changes.

```
enum DLViewLayout
{
    DLViewLayoutSolo = 1,
    DLViewLayoutDual = 2
};
enum DLViewFixedHorizontalProperty
{
    DLViewFixedHorizontalPropertyWidth = 4, // View margins scale with the screen width.
    DLViewFixedHorizontalPropertyMargin = 8 // View width scales with the screen width.
};
enum DLViewFixedVerticalProperty
{
    DLViewFixedVerticalPropertyHeight = 16,
    DLViewFixedVerticalPropertyMargin = 32
};
enum DLViewHorizonalAlignment
{
    DLViewHorizonalAlignmentLeft = 64,
    DLViewHorizonalAlignmentCenter = 128,
    DLViewHorizonalAlignmentRight = 256
};
enum DLViewVerticalAlignment
{
    DLViewVerticalAlignmentTop = 512,
    DLViewVerticalAlignmentMiddle = 1024,
    DLViewVerticalAlignmentBottom = 2048
};
```

I wonder in what situation it would make sense to bitwise `OR` combine the enum values to pass a view state.

```
int viewState = DLViewLayoutSolo | DLViewFixedHorizontalPropertyWidth | DLViewFixedVerticalPropertyMargin | DLViewHorizonalAlignmentCenter | DLViewVerticalAlignmentMiddle;  
// viewState = 1189
```

I want the user of the class to configure all parameter. How can I enforce this?

Within the class I can retrieve the individual settings by bitwise `AND` combining the state.

```
if (viewState & DLViewLayoutSolo)
{
  // Set up solo view layout.
}
else if (viewState & DLViewLayoutDual)
{
  // Set up dual view layout.
}
```

Comment: The programming language is C++.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to combine flags using values from differing enumerations?

This is *never* going to be best practice, in fact, I've never seen it in *any* practice, good or bad. This way, among other issues, any element utilising an instance which exposes a property of these flags must know, or be expected to know, that it's an amalgamation of values from these differing `enum` types.

Since the values ascend accordinly, why not simply use an aptly named enumeration consisting of all members?

Also, if we're talking .NET here (although legal, the semi-colons tell me maybe not), such `enum` types should be decorated with the `[Flags]` attribute, but still, only combine values of the same `enum` type.

Comment: Taking your suggestion: How would I prevent an invalid combination of values using an enum consisting of all members? Example: `.. | DLViewHorizonalAlignmentLeft | DLViewHorizonalAlignmentRight | ..`

Comment: @JJD: Check if both `DLViewHorizonalAlignmentLeft` and `DLViewHorizonalAlignmentRight` exist in the given flag-set and handle as (going to be) documented, defined by what the view expects.

Comment: Yes, but you only want the user of the class to pass one or the other. I guess, I cannot ensure that.

Comment: No, it can only be constrained to types, I guess, but as it gets to a lower level (scrutinising values of types) then I suppose you have to go with a handling mechanism, such as, but not necessarily advocating in every instance, raising exceptions. I'd probably laugh if I received a `RTFMException` when trying to configure a type with flag combinations, actually.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds as though you want fields whose values take on the state of each sub-condition:

```
enum DLViewLayout
{
    DLViewLayoutSolo,
    DLViewLayoutDual
};
enum DLViewFixedHorizontalProperty
{
    DLViewFixedHorizontalPropertyWidth, // View margins scale with the screen width.
    DLViewFixedHorizontalPropertyMargin // View width scales with the screen width.
};
enum DLViewFixedVerticalProperty
{
    DLViewFixedVerticalPropertyHeight,
    DLViewFixedVerticalPropertyMargin
};
enum DLViewHorizonalAlignment
{
    DLViewHorizonalAlignmentLeft,
    DLViewHorizonalAlignmentCenter,
    DLViewHorizonalAlignmentRight
};
enum DLViewVerticalAlignment
{
    DLViewVerticalAlignmentTop,
    DLViewVerticalAlignmentMiddle,
    DLViewVerticalAlignmentBottom
};

struct DLView {
    DLViewLayout layout;
    DLViewFixedHorizontalProperty fixed_horizontal;
    DLViewFixedVerticalProperty fixed_vertical;
    DLViewHorizonalAlignment horizontal;
    DLViewVerticalAlignment vertical;
};

// ...
DLView viewState;
// ...
if ( viewState.layout == DLViewLayoutSolo ) { ... }
else if ( viewState.layout == DLViewLayoutDual ) { ... }
}

/// repeat per field
```

If you are concerned about memory consumption, and have valid reason to be, then you can use the non-portable bit-field construct:

```
struct DLView {
    DLViewLayout layout : 1;
    DLViewFixedHorizontalProperty fixed_horizontal : 1;
    DLViewFixedVerticalProperty fixed_vertical : 1;
    DLViewHorizonalAlignment horizontal : 2;
    DLViewVerticalAlignment vertical : 2;
};
```

Comment: Nice idea. So I could encapsulate the total configuration set into a struct which will be the argument to be passed. Bitfields are new to me but that you for mentioning them. I already read about it.